# Grub from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, grub2

My Grub says Ubuntu 12, but I already have Ubuntu 14.04. Why does it say that the version is 12?There are too many options in the Grub menu, how can I clean it?

Answer (score 1):

May be you have installed Ubuntu 12 in another partition, that's why its being displayed in Grub Menu.

If in case you just have Ubuntu 14.04, then you can update Grub by typing this command in Terminal.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: thank you,

 I type the command, it ran and said done so i reboot, but nothing happended in the grub.

Comment: @RodrigoLeón Do you have ubuntu 12 installed in any other partition, if not you can edit the grub file.

Comment: Hello,

 I ran boot-repair and the grub itś "clean" now. Thank you for the answers.